# Low Battery Detection Circuit

Tags: led, circuit-design, tl431

I'm trying to light up an LED when my li-po battery level drops below 3 V. I have been using the scheme you can see in the picture.

The only change I have made has been to adjust the values of the resistive divider to activate the transistor from 3 V (R2 = 30 kΩ and R1 = 170 kΩ), and the LED I'm using is LTST-S310F3WT. However, I have not been able to switch the LED correctly.

[image]

Comment: Well, what are you measuring?

Comment: `not been able to switch the LED correctly` ... what does that mean? ... what actually happens?

Comment: I'm measuring the battery level of a li-po battery. The goal of the circuit is to turn the LED on when the level of the battery drops below 3 V. Currently, LED turns on  above the set low battery voltage level, 3V, which is not the desired performance.  It should be off in the 4.2V-3.1V range and turn on at 3V and below.